# updated values inside form do not transfer properly into new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

basically when you enter a value out of the specified range it gets updated to the minimum/maximum allowed, but the value of the var doesn't get updated to the max/min. (you can check by entering 1 into both forms and clicking on quote)
https://jsfiddle.net/epf4uyr6/

```
function cadCheck(input) {
  if (input.value < 2) input.value = 2;
  if (input.value >= 100) input.value = 99.99;
}


document.getElementById('cad').onkeyup = function() {
var cad = (this.value);
document.getElementById("cad-quote").innerHTML = "Market: $" +cad;
}
```

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: when you enter a value bigger/smaller than allowed, it gets saved even when its not allowed and changed.
for example you enter 1 for Bitcoin (it's more than 0.08 so I wrote the code to change it to 0.08 which is the maximum desired) but when you click quote it still shows 1, instead of 0.08

Comment: That's because `onkeydown` occurs before `onchange`. You store the value on keydow that why when the change event fires the value is already stored. why change the innerHTML on keyup of .bitcoin. Instead change it when the button is clicked.

Comment: got it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your values not updating properly because , keyup function executing first and then onchange(cadCheck) function execute.

your current logic is inside onchange function , thats why value not updating properly.

move this line in onkeyup function , and remove it from onchange.

```
document.getElementById('cad').onkeyup = function() {
                   if (this.value >= 100) this.value = 99.99;
                    var cad = (this.value);
                    document.getElementById("cad-quote").innerHTML = "Market: $" +cad;
                 }
```